# Used CSV DictReader to read in rows and filter based on lat long ranges

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have 179 GB of the following sparse data:

```
id    lat    long   var1    var2    var3
1     52.1   0.07    A       
2     58.3   5.78            C  
3     46.5  -8.32                    E
```

I want to read in the data, and filter so that only rows between certain lat long coordinates are kept. In this reprex the example range for latitude is 51.0 to 59.0, and the range of longitude is -1.0 to 6.0

All I have so far is a CSV dict reader and a dict comprehension that isn't working:

```
with open("test_data.csv", 'r', encoding="Latin-1") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['lat'] >= 51.0 if row['lat'] <= 59.0 if row['long'] >= -1.0 if row['long'] <= 6.0]
    print(rows)
```

Currently I get a TypeError: Unorderedable types: str() >= int() which is probably because DictReader brings things in as strings, and they need to be integer values. I am unsure as to how to insert int() into the dict comprehension.

Ultimately, I would like the output to select the following data:

```
id    lat    long   var1    var2    var3
1     52.1   0.07    A       
2     58.3   5.78            C
```

I'm ambivalent about the format of the dictionary, as I want to write the data back out to a csv afterwards.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it "isn't working"?

Comment: I think it's because I need to convert the lat longs to ints, as DictReader brings them in as strings.

Comment: I don't mean _why_ isn't it working, I mean _how_ isn't it working. Are you getting an error? Is the output incorrect? What is happening that makes you think it "isn't working"?

Comment: @asongtoruin I have amended the question

Comment: You should compare them as floats, as there are not integer values. You can cast to float with `float(row['lat'])`. Furthermore as to your tags, what you use is a list comprehension, although it is a list of dicts.

Comment: You should consider using `pandas`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you encounter memory issues, `pandas` should be able to do the job for you. You may need to install `pandas` first if you haven't already done so, but it should be easy using `pip` (and is a great package)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

filtered = df[(df['lat'].between(51.0, 59.0, inclusive=True)) &
              (df['long'].between(-1.0, 6.0, inclusive=True))]

filtered.to_csv('filtered_test_data.csv')
```

If you do encounter memory issues, use of the `chunksize` parameter lets you only read a certain amount of rows into memory. As your filtering is independent per row, we can apply this filtering per chunk and combine them all:

```
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', chunksize=1000000)

filtered = pd.concat([df[(df['lat'].between(51.0, 59.0, inclusive=True)) &
                         (df['long'].between(-1.0, 6.0, inclusive=True))]
                      for df in chunks])

filtered.to_csv('filtered_test_data.csv')
```

If this still doesn't work, you could try saving out each chunk and combining only at the end:

```
import pandas as pd

chunks = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', chunksize=1000000)

i = 0
for df in chunks:
    filtered = df[(df['lat'].between(51.0, 59.0, inclusive=True)) &
                  (df['long'].between(-1.0, 6.0, inclusive=True))]
    filtered.to_csv('chunk_{}.csv'.format(i))
    i += 1

final = pd.concat(pd.read_csv('chunk_{}.csv'.format(j)) for j in range(i))
final.to_csv('final.csv')
```

Comment: After trying to run this overnight, it got into memory difficulties and crashed. Is there a non Pandas version? That's why I originally asked for a CSV DictReader answer, as Pandas normally doesn't do well with large data sets (this is 179GB).

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge see the edit. Pandas can deal with a lot, I wouldn't write it off so fast!

Comment: whuft though actually, it still might crash on 179gb.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the chunk size and confirm the answer if it works!

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge it'll depend on how many records match your criteria - the use of `chunksize` lets pandas iterate through the files, so at any point it'll have the current chunk plus the matches found in any previous chunks in memory.